# "expected initializer before `<' token" with inline template function in global namespace

Tags: templates, g++

I am trying to compile some code, in one of my headers I have the following function in the global namespace:

```
template <class T>
inline
T
to_type<T> (const std::string& string)
{
    std::stringstream ss(string);
    T value;
    ss >> value;
    return value;
}
```

Yet somehow, this throws the g++ error `expected initializer before '<' token` (I changed one of the quotes to solve a conflict with the SO formatting)

I don't understand this error. Why is `to_type` not a valid initializer? This is the first time this symbol has been used. How do I fix this snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
template <class T>
inline
T
to_type(const std::string& string)
{
    std::stringstream ss(string);
    T value;
    ss >> value;
    return value;
}
```

(note no `<T>` after `to_type`).

`<>` are only put after the name of the function (or class) being declared when declaring a specialization, not when declaring the base template.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference, when encountering such an error, how would I go about finding out something like that? Just so I don't have to bother SO with beginner's questions

Comment: I think for questions about template syntax, asking is probably the best way to find out.

Comment: Or you could check the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html)